# Error : fork() failed in code generation

Tags: ibm-streams

I am developing one application for my client with IBM Streams v4.2
While compiling, I am getting the following error:

> /opt/ibm/InfoSphere_Streams/4.2.0.0/system/impl/bin/spl-code-gen-driver:
>   CDISP0139E ERROR: The execution of the code generator failed. The
>   error is: fork() failed.

Can anyone help as to where can I look for the actual error?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your environment, or the application you are trying to compile?

Comment: I am migrating my code from v3.0 to v 4.2 . I am building my application with TEDA framework in VMWare.Its basically an ETL job .I have run 4.2 script to generate frameworkand did modifications in that. I am just getting error mentioned above. Nothing else is given.Memory given to VMware is 4736 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fork() failing generally means the system is overloaded and out of resources.  Try terminating processes that you don't need, and if that doesn't work could you try increasig the memory for the VM and then or restarting the OS?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved now. fork() is due to too many processes running.Since I could not make out which process to kill, I restarted the system and immediately compiled the code after it was started.My code was compiled successfully.

For a permanent solution, I reduced the number of parallel threads/chain in the code so that the system does not run out of resources.It worked !!!